# VCdim of concentric circles

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

I have researched this topic in the last time, but no usefull results for me. So I'm here and I please you to help me with the following problem:

What is $VCdim$($\mathcal{H}$), where $\mathcal{H}$ is the class of concentric circles centred in origin in the 2D plane?

Comment: Can you please define formally this class $\mathcal{H}$? Or at least explain what "concentric circles" means, for us who aren't familiar with this concept?

Comment: I don't even see how concentric circles can shatter any two distinct points at the same distance from the origin, e.g., $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Then the VC dimension is either $0$ or $1$ depending on the details of the model (does the circle include the boundary, and can I place a point on $(0,0)$?)

Comment: @Steven Well, since the circles are pairwise disjoint, they cannot shatter *any* set of two distinct points. So that should be the answer.

Comment: @nirshahar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentric_objects

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained what you mean by *circle*. Let me consider three possible interpretations:

1. The set of points at distance *exactly* $r$ from the origin, for some $r$.
2. The set of points at distance *at most* $r$ from the origin, for some $r$.
3. The set of points at distance *less than* $r$ from the origin, for some $r$.

In all cases, it is easy to see that the concept class shatters any single point except, possibly, the origin. In contrast, we can show that no set of two points is shattered, and so the VC dimension is 1. Indeed, if $x,y$ are at the same distance from the origin and $C$ is an origin-centered circle, then $x \in C$ iff $y \in C$, and so $\{x,y\}$ is not shattered. If $x$ is closer to the origin from $y$, then in case 1, no origin-centered circle contains both, and in the other two cases, no origin-centered circle contains $y$ but not $x$; in all cases, $\{x,y\}$ is not shattered.

Comment: Only 1. is a *circle*; 2. and 3. are *disks*.